# Unable to get property 'ClientVariables' of undefined or null reference in CRM 2016 Online

Tags: security, dynamics-crm, crm

I have seen this question answered a few times for older versions of CRM but none of the solutions mentioned worked for me. Most answers specify giving read permissions to the Security Role on the Campaign and Sales Entities. The implementation I am working on doesn't use either but I tried anyway. Another suggestion was clearing cache. Neither of these worked and I still get the error.

I verified all roles in the system have read access to all Campaign and Sales entities.  I also verified their permissions for the Case entity under Services. It must have something to do with the case because I do not get this error on other entities/forms.

Any other ideas on what could lead to this error?

[Error Message when loading the Case form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX3fm.png)

**EDIT**:  I spent hours going through all of the field relationships (N:1, 1:N and N:N) for the Case entity and verified the related entities all have at least User read permissions. I even created spread sheet to show me which entities I need to update permissions for and which tab they are under on the Security Roles.  I verified 48 of the 59 entities with relationships have the read permissions.  The other eleven "entities" listed I can't edit permissions via the Security Roles screens.

Entities I can't find/edit:  Activity Party, Bulk Delete Failure, Duplicate Record, External Party, Image Descriptor, Owner, Post Regarding, Post Role, Process Stage, Text Analytics Topic and User Entity Instance Data.

Does anyone have any suggestions on fixing this issue if it isn't Security Role Related? Or how to update the permissions for these "entities?"

Answer (score 0):

Since this was an online issue, I didn't have access to all of the Guids for the various privileges. I had to create a Service ticket with Microsoft to have them help me investigate.

I did a live session with a Support Specialist and they captured all of the relevant data at the time of the error.

In the end, there was one ReadOnly permission missing from the Core Language entity.  This was not listed on any of the entity relationships so I hadn't updated it.  Once I added that permission, the forms started working again.